# Video not showing on smaller resolutions

Tags: themes

This is my first post here. 
The video on this [page](https://20four7va.com/beta/) is not showing up with smaller resolutions. Will be happy to have a solution. We are using the Jupiter theme for our site.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a CSS related issue than a Wordpress one, but it looks like you have a media query which hides the **mk-section-video** class when the window width is between 1024px and 320px.

Here is the CSS you'll need to remove inside your Jupiter theme stylesheet in order to keep the video displayed

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-device-width: 320px)
.mk-section-video {
    display: none!important;
}
```

In the Jupiter theme you can add CSS here..... Jupiter > Theme Options > Advanced > Custom CSS

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I hidden it from the section cause they have mentioned they are not allowing the video to display in the lower resolutions. Removed it now and still, the video is not loading in fullscreen. Can you check please?
added custom height of 500px

Comment: Yes, I can see you've added a 500px height. Do you want it to show on mobile (small devices)? If so, you will have to remove this css.......... @media (max-width: 767px)
.vc_hidden-xs { display: none!important; }

Comment: How can I remove it if it's coming from the theme main css file?

Comment: Maybe add this css to the stylesheet of your theme------>   .vc_video-bg { display: block !important; }

Comment: May I add it on the child theme?

Comment: Yes, in Jupiter theme you can add CSS here..... Jupiter > Theme Options > Advances > Custom CSS..... if that doesn't work you can visit the theme's doc site which offers more options https://themes.artbees.net/docs/inserting-custom-css-codes/

Comment: Ok, great! Let me try and get back with the results.

Comment: I added this to the specific page and the video shows up but doesn't play on cell phone devices. Other devices are just fine! Can you pls check?
P.S - Also the pictures cut out.

Comment: That's good news it's now displaying on all devices. You can add some extra CSS to size the video better on smaller screens. Not sure why its not playing on your mobile, that seems like a separate javascript issue. Your best option is to construct a new question on here or Stack Overflow. If you're happy with my help so far, I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct.